# Create two sequence http request by coroutine. Second request must wait when finish first

Tags: android, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines

Android studio 3.5
In my project I use retrofit and kotlin.
I want to the next steps by Kotlin coroutine:

1. Start first http request by retrofit.
2. Only after success finish then start second http request by retrofit.
3. If first request fail then NOT start second request.

Is it possible to do this by Kotlin coroutines?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's totally doable with coroutines:

```
interface MyApi{
    @GET
    suspend fun firstRequest(): Response<FirstRequestResonseObject>
    @GET
    suspend fun secondRequest(): Response<SecondRequestResponseObject>
}
```

Now, the call:

```
coroutineScope.launch{
  //Start first http request by retrofit.
  val firstRequest = api.getFirstRequest()
  if(firstRequest.isSuccessFul){
    //Only after success finish then start second http request by retrofit.
    val secondRequest = api.getSecondRequest()
  }
 //If first request fail then NOT start second request.
}
```

But, you might wanna consider your exceptions:

```
val coroutineExceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler{_, throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace()
}
```

And then:

```
coroutineScope.launch(coroutineExceptionHandler ){
      val firstRequest = api.getFirstRequest()
      if(firstRequest.isSuccessFul){
        val secondRequest = api.getSecondRequest()
      }
    }
```

Done!

For this approach, you must have retrofit 2.6 or above. Otherwise your responses should be `Deferred<Response<FirstResponseObject>>` and the requests `api.getFirstRequest().await()`

Comment: for me using deferred is more clear of a syntax, since you explicitly call await and you have more control over request.

Comment: I think I have to disagree with you. On the new version of Retrofit, Retrofit does that for you. There is no need to do it manually

Comment: oh my bad, I did not see that you change from deferred to suspend function, in that case yes it is better.